# sed specific line numbers substitution (swapping)

Tags: bash, sed

Let's say I have this list:

```
apple
orange
banana
kiwi
strawberry
```

How can I swap the value of line 2 (`orange`) with the value of line 4 (`kiwi`) to get this:

```
apple
kiwi # before "orange"
banana
orange # before "kiwi"
strawberry
```

Comment: If your "list" is in a file, this is much easier with `ed` than with `sed`: http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.shell/using-sed-to-swap-two-lines-in-a-file/498772

Comment: sed only has one permanent variable, the hold buffer. Your task requires the storage of banana and orange, as well as swapping their order.  In may be possible with **sed** and a temporary file, but will be much easier with **awk** or **perl**.

Comment: If you can assume that the words you want to swap will appear only in pairs, then you can just blindly change each to the other.

Comment: Since `sed` is a rather unnatural choice for this job, I suppose this is some sort of exercise.  How about showing us what you've already tried?  Or if you're having trouble even getting started, then look into some of `sed`'s less-used commands, such as those that manipulate the hold space, and the `N` command that appends the next input line to the pattern space.

Answer (score 1):

For a solution specifically working on lines 2 and 4:

```
$ sed '2{N;N;s/^\(.*\)\(\n.*\n\)\(.*\)$/\3\2\1/}' infile
apple
kiwi
banana
orange
strawberry
```

When reaching line 2, this adds the next two lines to the pattern space and then swaps the first and the last line.

To generalize this using the same approach, the number of `N` (and `\n` in the second capture group) would have to increase accordingly, and your best bet would probably be to write a script to generate the sed command.

Another option, but GNU sed specific: the `e` command, which allows to pipe results from a shell command to pattern space.

```
sed -e '2{e'"sed -n '4{p;q}' infile" -e 'd}' \
-e '4{e'"sed -n '2{p;q}' infile" -e 'd}' infile
1 apple
4 kiwi
3 banana
2 orange
5 strawberry
```

This combines an `e` and a `d` command for both lines 2 and 4, each extracting the desired line and deleting the current line. Maybe it would be possible to not resort to `-e` to split up the command, but escaping got pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it with sed, but with gnu awk you could do (with your list in `fruits.txt`) like this:

```
awk -v 'FS=\n' -v 'OFS=\n' -v 'RS=' '1 {print $1, $4, $3, $2, $5}' fruits.txt
```

The various `-v ...` set input and output field separator to newline , and clear the record separator.

Comment: `-v 'FS=\n' == -F'\n'`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v first=2 -v second=4 'FNR==NR{if(NR==second)s=$0; next}
                           FNR==first{f=$0; $0=s}
                           FNR==second{$0=f} 1' fruits{,} 

apple
kiwi
banana
orange
strawberry
```

swaps rows specified by variables first and second by double scanning the file.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '2{:a;N;4!ba;s/([^\n]*)(\n?.*\n)(.*)/\3\2\1/}' file
```

Focus on line 2 and append lines to the pattern space (PS) until the required line (in this case line 4). Then use pattern matching to reorder the lines.

N.B. This can be used to replace any pair of lines (even adjacent lines).